# How to create a loop to calculate phylogenetic signal and store results in several vectors in R

Tags: r, for-loop, storing-data

I need to calculate the phylogenetic signal of more than 100 variables and store the results 'K stats' and 'p-value' to create a dataframe where I have 3 columns specifying variable names, K-stats, and p-value. I know how to do it for 1 variable but I just don't want to repeat that process 100 times. Also, I think a loop could be a more efficient way to do it avoiding problems.

So this is how I think it should go, I just don't know how to implement it. First, some dummy data:

```
require(geiger)
require(phytools)
tree<-sim.bdtree(b=0.1,d=0,stop="taxa",n=50,extinct=FALSE)
trait<-matrix(rTraitCont(compute.brlen(tree,power=5),model="BM"),50,10)
trait <- as.data.frame(trait)
rownames(trait)<-tree$tip.label

# This is how it is done for 1 variable at the time: 

trait.1 <- setNames(trait$V1, rownames(trait))
trait.1.test <- phylosig(tree, trait.1, method = 'K', test = T)
trait.1.test$K
trait.1.test$P
```

Then I think that it should be a for loop with this structure:

```
# list1 <- list()
# List.Of.Kvalues <- list()
# List.Of.Pvalues <- list()


#For loop {
  # First I need a list that containes each column with the tree tip names or row names of the original data frame (this two are equal)
    # list1 <- list(setName(trait[col1], rownames(trait)))
  #Second I will use each list inside list1 to calculate the phylogenetic signal and stored the K value and another with p-values
    # List.Of.Kvalues <- phylosig(tree, list1[], method = K, test = T)$K
    # List.Of.Pvalues <- phylosig(tree, list1[], method = K, test = T)$P
# }

#Finally create the dataframe
# df <- rbind(colnames(trait),List.Of.Kvalues, List.Of.Pvalues)
```

My knowledge of how to preform loops is very basic, I hope somebody can help me understand how to build this kind of loops. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `for` loops :

```
library(geiger)
library(phytools)
#Initializtion part
tree<-sim.bdtree(b=0.1,d=0,stop="taxa",n=50,extinct=FALSE)
trait<-matrix(rTraitCont(compute.brlen(tree,power=5),model="BM"),50,10)
trait <- as.data.frame(trait)
rownames(trait)<-tree$tip.label
n <- ncol(trait)
Kvalues <- numeric(n)
Pvalues <- numeric(n)

#Loop over each column and get K and p values
for(i in seq_len(n)) {
  trait.1 <- setNames(trait[[i]], rownames(trait))
  trait.1.test <- phylosig(tree, trait.1, method = 'K', test = T)
  Kvalues[i] <- trait.1.test$K
  Pvalues[i] <- trait.1.test$P
}
```

Create a dataframe combining all values

```
out <- data.frame(colname = names(trait), K = Kvalues, P = Pvalues)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ronak! It worked beautifully! Now I understand better where I was stuck. Sometimes is hard to understand how to connect the vector part of the for loop with the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R you could use `lapply` to apply the test to each column

```
cbind(do.call("rbind.data.frame", lapply(trait, function(x) {
  data <- setNames(x, rownames(trait))
  test <- phylosig(tree, data, method = 'K', test = TRUE)
  list(K = test$K, P = test$P)
})), trait=names(trait))
```

Maybe a little prettier with `dplyr`'s `bind_rows`

```
library(dplyr)
Map(function(x) {
    data <- setNames(x, rownames(trait))
    test <- phylosig(tree, data, method = 'K', test = TRUE)
    list(K = test$K, P = test$P)
  }, trait) %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows(, .id="trait")
```

Note that for your example this returns the same values for every row because the columns of `trait` all see to be identical.

Comment: why `Map` and not `lapply` in 2nd option?

Comment: @RonakShah Map preserves the names of the values in the names of the resulting list. bind_rows needs a named list when using .id. lapply does not name the list if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: I see, I guess `sapply(..., simplify = FALSE)` behaves similar.

Comment: This is a good answer to the problem as stated.  (But should `trait.1.test` be indexed in some way to loop over traits?) I suspect OP's life would be simpler in the long run if they made their data [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  In this case, rather than having 100 traits in 100 variables, store all the traits in a single variable with an indicator variable to identify the trait being referenced.  Without a MWE, it's difficult to offer more concrete advice.

Comment: @Limey Ah yes. Had a typo. Forgot to change the variable amen.